# Set in python replacing number 10 from a file with 0,1

Tags: python-3.x, file, set

I have a file with the line:1 2 3 4 5 10. When I add this line to a set in Python, I get {1,2,3,4,5,0} instead of {1,2,3,4,5,10}. How do I code so that I get the 10 inside the set instead of it recognizing it as a 1 and a 0?

**EDIT**: This was the code I wrote:

```
states = set()
line = open("filepath", "r").readlines()[0]
states.add(line)
print (states)
```

Input file content:

```
1 2 3 4 5 10
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! 
1. Post one-two sample lines present in your input file, to show in what way your data is present.
2. Post some sample code to show what you have tried so far, so that we can help you find your mistake.

Comment: [Please see the help section detailing how to ask a good question on StackOverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

> *As set cannot have a same number twice, the zero which belongs to 10 is being treated as a unique element thus set cannot contain two same elements.*

Do something like this to fix it *(Assuming you don't have newline characters, if you do, just use the strip method.)*:

```
line = open("filepath", "r").readlines()[0]
line = line.split(' ') #Split by Space
number_set = set(line) #Since file is a list after splitting.
```

Comment: question is about working with one line, not the entire file. Would probably be better to work with `readline()` in a loop. Also reusing `file` as a file object and contents and list of strings is a bad idea.

Comment: @avigil, when i answered this question, it did not contain the code which it does now that's why i didn't had a clear idea. Also as the code is in python3, using `file` as a variable is nothing to worry about as far as i know, please let me know what demerits it has according to you?

Comment: i was more talking about reusing the same name for different things, which makes code difficult to read. doing `line = line.split(' ')` means in some places `line` is a string, in others its a list of strings.